# Presetting input values and allowing user to change

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm getting a bit more familiar with React, but I've come into the issue of inputs.

I'm generating inputs based on a user input, so if they select 1, I return a 2 input boxes, 2 then I return 4 input boxes.
In addition I want to pre-fill the input boxes with calculated numbers. Let's say they're min and max range

So I have something like this:

```
minArr = [];
maxArr = [];
for (let i = 0; i < this.state.userSelectInputAmount; i++) {
    minArr.push(this.calculateMin(item);
    maxArr.push(this.calculateMax(item);
}
return Array(this.state.userSelectInputAmount).fill().map((_, i) => {
    return (
      <div className="form-group">
        <label>
          <input className="form-control"
                 placeholder="Minimum Range"
                 type="number"
                 value={minArr[i]}
                 step="any" />
          <input className="form-control"
                 placeholder="Maximum Range"
                 type="number"
                 step="any"
                 value={maxArr[i]} />
        </label>
      </div>
```

The `min` and `max` are splits, respective to user input
Say they choose `1` then the range can be from `1 to 10`.
If they select 2 then `1 to 5` and `6 to 10`.

Using `value` allows me to rerender the options, but not allow users to customize their own input (`1 to 7` rather than `1-10`). Reading the documents, defaultValue shouldn't be a good option since I want the ability to re-render in the future (i.e. user input). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to keep the current value of all the inputs in state (or in a flux implementation, but the simplest solution is just in state). Initialize all of the values with the defaults you want, and pass them in to each input as `value`. Each input should then have an `onChange` handler that calls `setState` to update the value. That way, when a user changes an input, the state is updated to reflect the new change, and then the input is updated to display the same value that the user typed. It sounds a little silly but it's common practice with React.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, it's leading me on a path to keep `value`. So I have it similarly set up, except now I have all the `minArr` and `maxArr` stored as a state and I can iterate through those for the values. There's something wrong with how I'm setting it up. I still have `value={this.state.minArr[i]` I really want to use `this.state.value` but it won't work since I'm getting my values preloaded onto `minArr/maxArr`

Comment: Can you update your question to include this code? I can't quite follow based on your description.

Comment: Woo! So I thought I did follow this better, but the main key to this was using `refs` to parse the current input :)

Answer (score 0):

So I used `defaultValue` but I used `onChange={this.forceUpdate}` and now it works.

Comment: This is not a good use of forceUpdate. See the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#forceupdate) "Normally you should try to avoid all uses of forceUpdate() and only read from this.props and this.state in render(). This makes your component "pure" and your application much simpler and more efficient."